# Can I use dimmable leds without a dimmer?

Tags: lighting, led

I recently bought "dimmable LED lights" without knowing exactly what this means. I did some research, and now I get it.  A dimmer is required to regulate the intensity of the lights, for which I don't have a need.

Is there any **problem** with using dimmable LEDs without a dimmer? Will they work normally? I don't actually  want to dim them, so I am not sure if I need a dimmer or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there won't be any problem. I've been using four "dimmable" BR30 LED floodlights in my recessed kitchen cans for some time now, and I don't have a dimmer. They just start at full brightness and stay there. You don't need to use these with a dimmer if you don't want to. No performance or longevity problems.

Answer (score 4):

Dimmable simply means a claim that they are compatible with a dimmer.
When used without a dimmer they will be at full brightness.